# TOP Calculator: How do I make a function to operate on the numbers in a string?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <title> Calculator </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>


<body>
    <header>
    <h1>Bria's Calculator</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="container">
        <form name="calculate">
            <input id="input" type="text" name="output" placeholder="0"><br/>

            <input id="button1" type="button" value="1"/>
            <input id="button2" type="button" value="2"/>
            <input id="button3" type="button" value="3"/>
            <input id="button/" type="button" value="/"/> <br/>

            <input id="button4" type="button" value="4"/>
            <input id="button5" type="button" value="5"/>
            <input id="button6" type="button" value="6"/>
            <input id="button*" type="button" value="*"/><br/>

            <input id="button7" type="button" value="7"/>
            <input id="button8" type="button" value="8"/>
            <input id="button9" type="button" value="9"/>
            <input id="button-" type="button" value="-"/><br/>

            <input id="button(" type="button" value="("/>
            <input id="button)" type="button" value=")"/>
            <input id="button0" type="button" value="0"/>
            <input id="button+" type="button" value="+"/><br/>

            <input id="buttonc" type="button" value="c" style="background:red;"/>
            <input id="button." type="button" value="."/>
            <input id="button=" type="button" value="="/>
            <input id="button%" type="button" value="%"/><br/>

        </form>
    </div>
      


    <script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

```
const input=document.getElementById("input");
const container=document.getElementById("container");
const calc =document.getElementById("button=");


container.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    buttonClick(e.target.id);
});

//use event parameter of target to identify what's inside the id which are the buttons

calc.addEventListener("click", operate);

function buttonClick(buttonId){
    if ((buttonId !="buttonc") && (buttonId !="button=")){
        let button=document.getElementById(buttonId);
        let tmp=buttonId;
        tmp=tmp.replace("button", "");
        entries(tmp);
    }
};
//use 'replace' so when buttons are clicked it removes preface(button) and the id is just a number in the string format

function entries(tmp){
    input.value += tmp; 
}
//concatenating values entered by pressing buttons within container

function operate (){
    if(input.value=="."){
        alert("Please enter a math equation");
    } 
}
```

So far I've been able to get the numbers to concatenate in a string but now I need to actually operate on them. TOP discourages the use of eval so I just wanted to know how I could set up a function to add, divide, multiply and subtract the numbers I'm calling in the input form without eval(). I've provided my HTML code for context.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to convert your concatenated string to a number depending on the inputs you expect.  I would recommend one of these 2:

1. [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) - will convert a string with decimal points to a floating point number.
2. [`parseInt(x,10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) - will convert a string's integer value to an integer (will not process any decimal points). Notice the second argument (10).